# fetch data from firebase without getting uid key in React Native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get all data from firebase database but i dont want UID key to shown, from this code i can get data but it shows uid. I just want to display all the data with this if that's possible

[image]

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('/users');
    recentPostsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      // snapshot.val() is the dictionary with all your keys/values from the '/store' path
      console.log(snapshot.val());
    });
  }, []);
```

can i output this data in following manner ?

```
    {
      avatar: 'pin-1.png',
      firstname: 'Mahir',
      lastname: 'Asrani',
      latitude: 28.660918,
      longitude: 77.274468,
    },
    {
      avatar: 'pin-1.png',
      firstname: 'name',
      lastname: 'name',
      latitude: 00.00066,
      longitude: 00.275550,
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of values, you can use the `forEach` operator to extract all the values and put them in an array:

```
recentPostsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
  let values = [];
  snapshot.forEach((child) => {
    values.push(child.val());
  });
  console.log(values);
});
```

Two notes:

- You are still reading they keys from the database here, just not displaying them anymore. If that is what you want, that is great of course. Just want to make sure you know the keys are still read from the database by the client.
- It is very common for the app to need the key later, for example to identify a specific set of values, or to update a specific node in the database. You may have to come back to this code later and revisit it to also keep the keys. A simple way to keep both the keys, and values, but keep them separately is:

  ```
  recentPostsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    let keys = [],
        values = [];
    snapshot.forEach((child) => {
      key.push(child.key);
      values.push(child.val());
    });
    console.log(keys, values);
    // or: setState({ keys: keys, values: values });
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate using `forEach` to retrieve all the data under `users`:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    var recentPostsRef = firebase.database().ref('/users');
    recentPostsRef.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
      console.log(childSnap.val());
     });
    });
  }, []);
```

This will retrieve all the data under the `ids`, but you can still access the id if you do `let uid = childSnap.key`

Comment: Okay but i want to store all my data in a single state, so i can access it easily. i made this state
  const [data, setdata] = useState();

Comment: why cant you store `childSnap.val()` inside the state?

Comment: i just did it by making an array :) Thank you